# functions with malloc syntax error?

Tags: c, function, malloc

I am new to working with pointers and I have no idea why this does not work. If I print inside the `scan` function it works, but it has to be in a separate function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int scan(int n, int *buffer)
{
    int i;
    printf("nr of elements:\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    //int *buffer, i=0;
    // *buffer=(int*)malloc((*n) * sizeof(int));
    buffer = malloc((n + 1) * sizeof(*buffer));
    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
         buffer[i]=i+1;
         printf ("%d ", buffer[i]);}
         printf ("\n-------------\n");   
 }

 void print(int *n,int *buffer){
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
       printf ("%d ", buffer[i]);}
 }

 int main()
 {
    int n,i, *buffer;
    scan(&n, &buffer);
    print(n, *buffer);

    printf("i quit\n");
    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
       printf ("%d ", buffer[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `scan()` is not returning a value, and you declared it to return `int` what compiler are you using?

Comment: Did you get any compiler warnings/errors with the above code? If you did, please pay attention to them. If not, it's time to change your compiler.

Comment: You just want `print(n, buffer);`

Comment: you're doing `scan(&n ..)`, passing in a POINTER to your int, then treating that pointer as if it was an integer inside the function, then taking FURTHER pointers with `scanf(..., &n)`. `malloc(n` will also allocate as much ram as whatever your pointer is. e.g. if the main `n` lives at address 12345678, then you're going to be mallocing 12.3 meg of ram.

Comment: "Does not work" is not a valid problem description. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: That's not a compiler but I assume you are using `gcc` try adding options to `gcc`'s command, these options `-Wall -Wextra -Werror`.

Comment: C:\Users\W\Desktop\prog\ex\main.c|21|error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector|
C:\Users\W\Desktop\prog\ex\main.c||In function 'main':|
C:\Users\W\Desktop\prog\ex\main.c|27|warning: passing argument 1 of 'scan' makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]|
C:\Users\W\Desktop\prog\ex\main.c|3|note: expected 'int' but argument is of type 'int *'|

Comment: I use windows, not linux

Comment: So, on which line are you getting the syntax error? Also, what specifically does the compiler say? I doubt it's *only* "syntax error".

Comment: [this is the compiler log](http://i59.tinypic.com/2rm8msj.jpg)

Comment: You're also passing a `int**` to a function expecting `int*`. That should be another giant clue. It should be declared `int **buffer` , set a `*buffer = malloc(...);` used appropriately therein,and invoked as `scan(&n, &buffer)`. I would venture to say you need to spend more time learning how to pass in/out parameters via-address in C. If the thing you want to modify is a pointer, its just like anything else; pass its address and declare the formal parameter a pointer to... a pointer.

Comment: Please include the error message *as text* in the body of the question. A link in a comment to an image of the compiler log is not useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can help to use (slightly) more descriptive variable names to make it abundantly clear that 'n' in scan is not the same as 'n' in print:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void scan(int *np, int **bufferp)
{
    int i;
    printf("nr of elements:\n");
    scanf("%d", np);

    *bufferp = (int*)malloc(*np * sizeof(**bufferp));
    for(i=0; i < *np; i++){
      (*bufferp)[i] = i + 1;
      printf ("%d ", (*bufferp)[i]);
    }
    printf ("\n-------------\n");
 }

 void print(int n, int *buffer){
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
       printf ("%d ", buffer[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
 }

 int main()
 {
    int n, i, *buffer;
    /* pass references to n and buffer for scan to modify */
    scan(&n, &buffer);
    print(n, buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of changing parameters of function (change data outside function):

1) use references (in my example - the first argument of scan function)

2) use pointers (in my example - the second argument of scan... THIS ARGUMENT IS OF TYPE int*)

Try this (my comments show the changes):

```html
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void scan(int &n, int ** buffer) // pointer to pointer for bufer, void instead of int for function, and &int for n
{
    int i;
    printf("nr of elements:\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    *buffer = (int*) malloc( n * sizeof(**buffer)); // (int*) should be, and *buffer
    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
         (*buffer)[i]=i+1;   // *buffer
         printf ("%d ", (*buffer)[i]);  // *buffer
 }
    printf ("\n-------------\n");   
 }

 void print(int n, int *buffer)   // type of n changed from int* to int
 {
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
       printf ("%d ", buffer[i]);
 }
 }

 int main()
 {
    int n,i, *buffer = NULL;
    scan(n, &buffer);
    print(n, buffer); // buffer is pointer, no need to use *

    printf("i quit\n");
    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
       printf ("%d ", buffer[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note: if you whant to change data you can use

```html
void changeArgument(int * data) 
{
 (*data)++;
}
```

but to change addres of data, you should use

```html
void changeArgument(int ** pointer) 
{
 (*pointer) = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
}
```

Comment: References wokr in C++, so remame your file to *.cpp and use g++. I just explained two different options.

Comment: void scan(int *np, int **bufferp) - is not from my example

Answer (score 0):

Either declare the scan() with void return type and display the data their itself. 
OR if you want the function to return int then instead of printing it in the function return the value and display it in main(). It should work fine then.